# SQL Server: Combine two unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that don't have any relationship, I want to create a view that has a new `Key` column that can be used.

`StoreTable`:

```
StoreID     StoreName
----------  -------------
1           Store1
2           Store2
3           Store3
```

`StoreStageTable`:

```
StageID     StageDesc
----------  -------------
1           Pre
2           WorkInProgress
3           Completed
```

Expected results would be for each `StoreName` will be combined with each row from the `StoreStageTable`.

So `Store1` will have `Store1_Pre` and `Store1_WorkInProgress` and `Store1_Completed`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know how many rows there are and will always be? The SQL language has **very strict requirement** that you know the number and types of columns in the results for a query before looking at **any** data. If you have to look into the data to know about the result columns, you won't be able to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching a *[cartesian](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-cartesian-join-self-join/)* join. It means combine rows with other table rows.

```
SELECT st.*, ss.*
FROM StoreTable st
CROSS JOIN StoreStageTable ss --there is no condition on CROSS join!
```